# Give GPT a material to base his answer on

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I have been tasked in integrating GPT as a consultant on a website. It is supposed to use a manual I have been provided with, but I don't know how to give the manual to it.

The only solution I have is to send the manual as a message with `{role: "system", content: "You answer according to the following manual: ~manual~"}`. The problem here is the token limit. Is there a better way to give GPT a material it should base the answer on?

Comment: relevant link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390463/starting-the-prompt-design-site-a-new-home-in-our-stack-exchange-neighborhood

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Cognitive Search feature of azure API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-azure-search